# How to flatten with a table wildcard in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

We recently switched to a standard setup with tables that are labeled by month (*foo_2015_05*) with a common format that contains a repeated field. Originally when I created a view based on one, large table, it forces me to FLATTEN the table on the repeated field.

When trying to update my view to account for the monthly tables, I can't seem to have both a table wildcard AND flatten at the same time.

```
SELECT blah
FROM FLATTEN(TABLE_QUERY(dataset, "tableid CONTAINS 'foo_'"), repeated_field)
```

gives me the following error:
*Table name cannot be resolved: dataset name is missing*

Am I missing something? Or is there a work-around for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the issue is that `FLATTEN` does not work a union of tables, which `TABLE_QUERY` is eventually rewritten to, if the `TABLE_QUERY` evaluates to multiple tables.  A workaround is to wrap the `TABLE_QUERY` in a subselect, making the `FLATTEN` operate over a single source, the subselect.

```
SELECT blah
FROM FLATTEN(
  (SELECT * FROM TABLE_QUERY(dataset, "tableid CONTAINS 'foo_'")), 
  repeated_field)
```

Comment: I was about to comment just that as a possible workaround, you, sir, beat me to the finish line!